# setLocation() function isn't allowing me to change the location of a JLabel on another JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I haven't programmed in java in a long time so I'm getting very confused. I know the code is fairly unorganized and not very OO, but I'm wondering why my "Laser Dot" image won't move alone the "Map Tracker" image. I'm using it as a test for a GPS tracker project I will be doing. I just want the red dot image to be able to move along the map image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {


    BufferedImage img = null;
    BufferedImage redDot = null;

    try {
        System.out.println(new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/MapTracker.jpg").exists());
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/MapTracker.jpg"));
        redDot = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/LaserDot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Window");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1366,768);
    int w = img.getWidth(null);
    int h = img.getHeight(null);

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.setLayout(null);
    JLabel dot = new JLabel();

    frame.add(label);

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    label.add(dot);
    dot.setLocation(1000,300);
    dot.setBounds(100,100,500,500);


    g.drawImage(redDot, 0, 0, null);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.draw(new Line2D.Double(0.0,0.0,500.0,500.0));
    System.out.println("Image Drawn");

}

}
```

The drawline can be ignored. It is not pertinent to my problem.

Comment: Can you put try/catch block to find the exception by any of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your Laser dot image is not moving, because you are not moving it. After you draw Laser dot you do not touch it again. For it to move you need some update loop to redraw it after its position changes. To get more info take a look at some game tutorial. For [example](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `dot` label doies not have any content. Put your `redDot` image as icon on it and you'll see something.

Furthermore, you don't need to call `setLoaction()` *and* `setBounds()`. The x- and y-location of your dot-label is already included in the `setBounds()`:

```
    ...
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);   // your map background as icon
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);    // your map background label
    label.setLayout(null);
    JLabel dot = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(redDot));  // you need to put some content in your dot label - like 

    frame.add(label);

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    label.add(dot);
    //  dot.setLocation(1000, 300);     // when you use setBounds, you don't need location
    dot.setBounds(50, 50, 60, 60);  // x-location, y-location, with, height
    dot.revalidate();   // just to make sure that your dot actually takes the new bounds and paints it
```

Sorry, forgot to mention that you create your view only once without updating it in any way. Which explains that there is no movement.

Here is an example how you could achieve a movement / animation. But there are so many different possibilities and it really depends – so it's just an example:

```
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    frame.setSize(w, h);        // I just did that to make the example easier to understand

    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));  // so your "background" label with the map image
    // we need this dot label somewhere else and it must be final
    final JLabel dot = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(redDot));  // and your dot label with the dot image as icon

    label.add(dot);
    frame.add(label);
    label.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);    // just for the example, the map-label is set to  fill the frame
    dot.setBounds(50, 50, 60, 60);  // setBounds will handle both: location and size
    frame.pack();  // pack will do all the stuff to make sure everything is painted and has the correct size when the window becomes visible

    // and here comes the animation:
    // my solution is to use a swing timer. Swing timers execute in a background thread and are perfectly suited to "update" any swing component without blocking the User Input thread.
    // this timer will call the actionPerformed() of the ActionListener every 500 ms
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Point location = dot.getLocation();    // get current location of the dot
            dot.setLocation(location.x + 10, location.y + 10);  // just set a new location 10 px further right and further down
            dot.revalidate();  // revalidate, so the updated position will be taken into account when the dot label will get painted again
        }
    });
    timer.start();   // start the timer and it will immediately start moving your dot on the img
```